# Problemas con un trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un trigger con un simple update.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `reCalibrados` AFTER INSERT ON `calibrationtbl`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE calibrationtbl SET state='1' WHERE idInteva=
        (SELECT idInteva FROM calibrationcertificatestbl WHERE 
        Month(nextCalDate)= Month(NOW()) AND Year(nextCalDate)= YEAR(NOW()));
    END;//
    delimiter ;
```

Me da este error:

> Unrecognized statement type (near end);

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta con otra indicación para corregir el problema. Espero.

Comment: Por favor prueba reduciendo la posibles causas del error. Conserva la "nueva" definición del trigger con el uso del delimitador y simplifica el UPDATE, por ejemplo: `UPDATE calibrationtbl SET state='1' WHERE idInteva=[ID_CONOCIDO]` para ver si pasa algo con el uso de esa subconsulta

Comment: Ya lo he hecho :) Sí crea el Trigger a pesar de que marca error en el END, y no lo ejecuta.

Comment: Una cosa es que lo cree y otra que quede creado con errores :) Si se define el update sin ponerlo dentro del bloque begin...end, qué pasa?

Comment: No lo ejecuta, Y el INSERT del cual depende, tampoco lo ejecuta

Comment: ese es el problema si no ejecuta el insert no va a ejecutar el trigger.

Comment: Ajam, pero cuando quito el trigger la consulta funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la subconsulta, falta un espacio antes del AND

`WHERE...Month(NOW()) AND Year(nextCalDate)=YEAR(NOW()))`

Así mismo, usaría un delimitador para definir el trigger

```
  DELIMITER $$

  CREATE TRIGGER...
     .....
  END */$$
  DELIMITER ;
```

En la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html), dan un ejemplo de cómo crearlo usando un bloque de transacción y requiere usar delimitadores especiales para que pueda distinguir entre el fin del bloque del trigger y el final de la instrucción DDL (por eso "falla" en el END)

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 0;
    ->     ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
    ->         SET NEW.amount = 100;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Comment: Gracias, buena observación, pero el error me lo marca en el END, y no sé por qué.

Comment: Podrías poner el código completo? incluyendo el comienzo con 'create trigger...'

Comment: Me sigue dando error aun usando delimitadores